# Hide server logs for send_file method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, ruby-on-rails-4

Rails version: 4.2.0

Ruby version: 2.3.8

Is there any way in a Rails application to hide the absolute path displayed for the `send_file` method?

controller code:

```
def download_file(file_path)
  send_file file_path, :x_sendfile => true, :type => 'application/pdf'
end
```

the path displayed in server logs:

```
Sent file /home/new_user/Project/new_project/pdfs/plan_7.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the `config/production.rb` and change log level.

Try something like that:

```rb
  config.log_level = :fatal
```

The level can be: `:debug`, `:info`, `:warn`, `:error`, `:fatal`, and `:unknown`. Choise the best option for your case.